# Subset dataframe by many factors at the same time in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, factors

I have a data frame with several variables: region, season, year, altitude and response (here an example):

```
region   season   year   altitud   response
IT       wint     2013   800       45
IT       wint     2013   815       47
IT       wint     2013   840       54
IT       wint     2014   800       49
IT       wint     2014   815       59
```

and so on. There are three regions, four seasons and two years, and I would like to perform several linear modeling and plotting between altitud and response, subsetting the data according all possible combinations. i.e.

```
subset(region&season&year)   and get  altitud~response
IT&wint&2013
IT&wint&2014
IT&spring&2013
IT&spring&2014
```

and so on. Therefore, 24 combinations. Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance

David

Comment: Look at many models using `purrr` I think.

Comment: You can use `split()` to get a list of your subsets. ... then `lapply()`

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses `broom` with `tidy` functions.

Reading the data:

```
library(readr)

data <- read_table("region   season   year   altitud   response
IT       wint     2013   800       45
IT       wint     2013   815       47
IT       wint     2013   840       54
IT       wint     2014   800       49
IT       wint     2014   815       59")
```

Actual solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
data_fit <- data %>%
    group_by(region, season, year) %>%
    do(fit = lm(altitud ~ response, data = .))

dfCoefs <- tidy(data_fit, fit)
dfCoefs
```

Which gives the following regression coefficients for the example data:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Groups:   region, season, year [2]
  region season  year term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 IT     wint    2013 (Intercept)   613.      34.7       17.7    0.0360
2 IT     wint    2013 response        4.22     0.711      5.93   0.106 
3 IT     wint    2014 (Intercept)   726.     NaN        NaN    NaN     
4 IT     wint    2014 response        1.5    NaN        NaN    NaN
```

Though, do you want `altitud ~ response` (i.e. predict altitude from response) or `response ~ altitud` (predict the response given the altitude?)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am quite new to R programming, so I create a far less gentle code (using split and tidy functions). I will try yours anyway. The response would be the Y and the altitude the X

Comment: No problem, I hope everything worked out. Just remember to use `Y ~ X` for regression formulas (in this case `response ~ altitud`). :) You can read the documentation for the `formula` function for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I got you right, here's a purrr solution:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
nested<-df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character,as.factor) %>% 
  group_by(year,season,region) %>% 
  nest()
my_model<-function(df){
  lm(altitud~response,data=df)
}

nested %>% 
  mutate(Mod=map(data,my_model))
```

Result: Partially modified the data to get factors.

```
 A tibble: 3 x 5
   year season region data             Mod     
  <int> <fct>  <fct>  <list>           <list>  
1  2013 wint   IT     <tibble [3 x 2]> <S3: lm>
2  2014 wint   IT     <tibble [1 x 2]> <S3: lm>
3  2014 Summer IF     <tibble [1 x 2]> <S3: lm>
```

Predicting with `modelr`. You can get stats using `broom` as shown by the other answer.

```
require(modelr)
nested %>% 
  mutate(Mod=map(data,my_model)) %>% 
  mutate(Preds=map2(data,Mod,add_predictions)) %>% 
  unnest(Preds)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
   year season region altitud response  pred
  <int> <fct>  <fct>    <int>    <int> <dbl>
1  2013 wint   IT         800       45  44.4
2  2013 wint   IT         815       47  47.9
3  2013 wint   IT         840       54  53.7
4  2014 wint   IT         800       49  49  
5  2014 Summer IF         815       59  59
```

Getting summary stats with `broom` and `purrr`:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
   year season region term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <int> <fct>  <fct>  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1  2013 wint   IT     (Intercept) -140.      31.8        -4.40   0.142
2  2013 wint   IT     altitud        0.231    0.0389      5.93   0.106
3  2014 wint   IT     (Intercept)   49      NaN         NaN    NaN    
4  2014 Summer IF     (Intercept)   59      NaN         NaN    NaN

nested %>% 
  mutate(Mod=map(data,my_model)) %>% 
  mutate(Preds=map2(data,Mod,add_predictions),Tidy=map(Mod,tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(Tidy)
```

Data:

```
df<-read.table(text="region   season   year   altitud   response
IT       wint     2013   800       45
               IT       wint     2013   815       47
               IT       wint     2013   840       54
               IT       wint     2014   800       49
               IF       Summer     2014   815       59",header=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here are also base R and [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) solutions.

#### Base R

One possible base R approach using `split()` and `lapply()` was [suggested by Jogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460828/subset-dataframe-by-many-factors-at-the-same-time-in-r#comment95729798_54460828):

```
result <- lapply(split(DT, list(DT$region, DT$season, DT$year)), 
                 lm, formula = response ~ altitud)
print(result)
```

> ```
> $IT.wint.2013
>
> Call:
> FUN(formula = ..1, data = X[[i]])
>
> Coefficients:
> (Intercept)      altitud  
>   -140.0510       0.2306  
>
>
> $IT.wint.2014
>
> Call:
> FUN(formula = ..1, data = X[[i]])
>
> Coefficients:
> (Intercept)      altitud  
>   -484.3333       0.6667
> ```

Or, using piping for improved readability

```
library(magrittr)
result <- split(DT, list(DT$region, DT$season, DT$year)) %>% 
  lapply(lm, formula = response ~ altitud)
```

#### data.table

With some help of `broom`:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(DT)[, lm(response ~ altitud, .SD) %>% broom::tidy(), by = .(region, season, year)]
```

> ```
>    region season year        term     estimate   std.error statistic   p.value
> 1:     IT   wint 2013 (Intercept) -140.0510204 31.82553603 -4.400586 0.1422513
> 2:     IT   wint 2013     altitud    0.2306122  0.03888277  5.930962 0.1063382
> 3:     IT   wint 2014 (Intercept) -484.3333333         NaN       NaN       NaN
> 4:     IT   wint 2014     altitud    0.6666667         NaN       NaN       NaN
> ```

```
setDT(DT)[, lm(response ~ altitud, .SD) %>% broom::glance(), by = .(region, season, year)]
```

> ```
>    region season year r.squared adj.r.squared    sigma statistic   p.value df    logLik      AIC    BIC deviance df.residual
> 1:     IT   wint 2013 0.9723576     0.9447152 1.111168  35.17631 0.1063382  2 -2.925132 11.85026 9.1461 1.234694           1
> 2:     IT   wint 2014 1.0000000           NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN  2       Inf     -Inf   -Inf 0.000000           0
> ```

---

If computing `lm()` for different groups is time consuming it might be worthwhile to store the result and use these for subsequent processing steps:

```
mod <- setDT(DT)[, .(model = .(lm(response ~ altitud, .SD))), by = .(region, season, year)]
mod
```

> ```
>    region season year models
> 1:     IT   wint 2013   <lm>
> 2:     IT   wint 2014   <lm>
> ```

`mod$models` is a list of models equivalent to `result`.

Now, we can extract the desired information from the computed models, e.g.,

```
mod[, models[[1]] %>% broom::tidy(), by = .(region, season, year)]
```

> ```
>    region season year        term     estimate   std.error statistic   p.value
> 1:     IT   wint 2013 (Intercept) -140.0510204 31.82553603 -4.400586 0.1422513
> 2:     IT   wint 2013     altitud    0.2306122  0.03888277  5.930962 0.1063382
> 3:     IT   wint 2014 (Intercept) -484.3333333         NaN       NaN       NaN
> 4:     IT   wint 2014     altitud    0.6666667         NaN       NaN       NaN
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("
region   season   year   altitud   response
IT       wint     2013   800       45
IT       wint     2013   815       47
IT       wint     2013   840       54
IT       wint     2014   800       49
IT       wint     2014   815       59")
```